# Wordpress custom fonts does not work

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face, font-family

i have super stupid problem.
I try to use custom fonts on my simple WP site and @font-face not working at all.
I even put whole path to font files and it work - you can download the font from my server. But i Can't use it on my website.

```css
@font-face {
 font-family:"Accidental Presidency";
src:url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/accid___.eot?') format("eot"),
url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/accid___.woff') format("woff"),
url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/accid___.ttf') format("truetype"),
url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/accid___.svg#AccidentalPresidency') format("svg");
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}


@font-face
{
 font-family:'nexa_regular';
 src:url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/nexa_regular.eot');
 src:url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/nexa_regular.eot?#iefix')format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/nexa_regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/nexa_regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('http://echoserca.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/fonts/nexa_regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

```css
  font-size: 9vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:white;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 0px;
        position: relative;
        font-family:'nexa_regular';
```

Comment: On Edge i have Error code:
CSS3116
 
"@font-face failed cross-origin request. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header."
 
The font might not be configured for cross-domain access.
 
The font is not served from the same origin as the document. Ensure that the host serving the font allows the use of this font by using the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"HTTP header.

Comment: but i have no idea what I can do with that.